# Arbitrary bg color values malfunctioning in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using arbitrary values to define the background color of a div. The hex code of the color are stored in `course.color` variable as a string. I am passing a formatted string as a classname to the div element.

However the background color is loading for some elements, and it is not loading for other.

When passing the color values directly through style attribute, the colors are shown correctly.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong? I need to use to tailwind syntax and don't want to send values via the style attribute.

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-center px-8 py-12 drop-shadow-xl bg-white rounded-lg">
    <div className={`bg-[${course.color}] p-4 w-16 h-16 rounded-sm`}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={course.icon} color={course.color} />
    </div>
    <span className='font-semibold text-xl my-4'>
        {course.name}
    </span>
    <p className='text-center text-[#696984]'>
        {course.desc}
    </p>
</div>
```

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNNH8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute like:

```
<div
  className="p-4 w-16 h-16 rounded-sm"
  style={{ backgroundColor: course.color }}
>
```

Comment: Why would you vote (righteously so) to close this question, then answer it with the duplicate content?  Seems counter intuitive to the system having a "Close for Duplicate Question" flag?  Granted you're the original answer .. But still this question should be closed and deleted by the system ..

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. Instead mark the question as duplicate.